# how to check is a button still pressed (clicked) or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

I need to know the state of the button at this time if clicked or not  ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (myButton.state & UIControlStateHighlighted) {
   // Do your stuff the user is currently holding down her finger…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the state property of your UIButton. You're interested in UIControlStateHighlighted.